# Provide external javascript dependency for JsTestDriver

Tags: js-test-driver

I want to test for example `A.js` which has dependecies from `B.js` which is stored in JAR archive. How can I configure the JSTestDriver to read dependencies from `B.js`?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't find a way to do this via JSTestDriver configuration file and JSTestDriver eclipse plugin, but done this with maven (i.e. during maven build tests) via maven-dependency-plugin, during phase prosess-test-resources run an unpack goal and put the unpacked javascript files to the folder which is visivble from jsTestDriver.conf configuration file.